# libreoffice basic How to set an empty string to a protected cell?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

If we start with a new sheet, protecting all cells besides $A$1.

If we furthermore assign the following macro to "Content changed" <-- "Sheet Events"

```
sub main
      
    fPos = ThisComponent.getSheets().getByName("Sheet1").getCellByPosition(0,0)
    sPos = ThisComponent.getSheets().getByName("Sheet1").getCellByPosition(0,1)

    sPos.string = fPos.string

end sub
```

If we than protect the sheet and start entering some values into field A1, these are all written into A2 as expected.

But how can we get an empty field A2 after such inputs without changing the sheet protection?

`sPos.clearContents(7)` doesn't help further.

Maybe, is this a bug?

Thx for any hints or a solution.

Comment: No, this is not a bug - "Content changed" does not really work for clearing a cell using Delete or Backspace. As a working workaround, you can use this trick `If Trim(fPos.string) = "" Then fPos.string = ""` before assigning `sPos.string = fPos.string`. You just need to explain to users that clearing the value is done with the spacebar. Yes, this is not very convenient for your task, but take it for granted.

Comment: *(I understand that you deliberately simplified your example to clearly describe the problem, but in fact the event handler does a lot more work. But if it is really only about duplicating the entered (or cleared) value in the adjacent cell, then just write the formula `=A1` in **A2** and do not run any macros.)*

Comment: You are right, the example is simplified, but the functionality is needed! About the bug question and the other things I'm not so sure. First: if you write a"space" and press "backspace" than "enter" or only use "backspace" the macro is called. You really change the content! So, this is an expected behavior.

Comment: Second: your trick doesnt work and this is the biggest problem. I cannot write an empty string to a protected cell as written in my question but any other value. This is for me an unexpected behavior. Maybe a bug? ;) This was tested on 6.x and 7.2 version of libreoffice.

Comment: The silly thing is if cell A2 is not protected, it takes the emtpy string assignment. ?!? Any explanation or other tricks to do that with protection on @JohnSUN?

Comment: I can’t explain - from my point of view this is really a bug. Let's go back to the idea of the formula in cell A2. Perhaps a function of the form `Function RelatedValue(sSource As String) As String : RelatedValue =Trim(sSource) : End Function` and the formula `=RELATEDVALUE(A1)` in cell A2 will allow you to bypass the error? Of course, the "Content changed" event handler should be disabled. Oh yes! Make sure that [**AutoCalculate**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/06070000.html) is not disabled.

Comment: Thx again for your answer and your efforts to overcome the bug. Sadly, I need the macro and the event handler. Do you like to report the issue? Otherwise where should I do it? Is there a prefered place? Thx for your advise.

Comment: Kindly visit [**Bugzilla**](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&content=Calc%20protected%20cell%20&no_redirect=1&order=Importance&product=LibreOffice&query_format=specific). Just first please check if this error is already among the registered ones.